# Return None - scraping p by Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

[image]I want to scrap name and number of product in stock but it return None.

```
data_insight = []

for n in range(pagenum):
    pages_url = f"https://www.insight.com/en_US/search.html?qtype=all&q=tp-link&qsrc=k&pq=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A100%2C%22currentPage%22%3A{n+1}%2C%22shownFlag%22%3Afalse%2C%22priceRangeLower%22%3Anull%2C%22priceRangeUpper%22%3Anull%2C%22cmtStandards%22%3Atrue%2C%22categoryId%22%3Anull%2C%22setType%22%3Anull%2C%22setId%22%3Anull%2C%22shared%22%3Anull%2C%22groupId%22%3Anull%2C%22cmtCustomerNumber%22%3Anull%2C%22groupName%22%3Anull%2C%22fromLicense%22%3Atrue%2C%22licenseContractIds%22%3Anull%2C%22assortmentIds%22%3Anull%2C%22controller%22%3Anull%2C%22fromcs%22%3Afalse%2C%22searchTerms%22%3A%7B%22TP-LINK%2520TECHNOLOGY%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22field%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22A-HYBRIS-ManufacturerId~0007045098%22%7D%7D%2C%22sortBy%22%3A%22BestMatch%22%7D"
driver.get(pages_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="prod-section-container"]')))
html = driver.page_source
soup = Soup(html)
soup

    for item in soup.select('[class="prod-section-container"]'):
    data_insight.append({
        'title' : item.find("a", class_="select-prod").text,
        'name' : item.find("p", string="Insight Part"),
        'link' : item.find("a", class_="select-prod")['href'],
        'price' : item.find("span", class_="c-currency__value"),
        'stock' : item.find("p", class_="prod-stock").text
    })
    
df_insight = pd.DataFrame(data_insight)
df_insight.drop_duplicates()
df_insight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

With `string` you can search for strings instead of tags, but in the way you do it looks for exact match.

#### How to fix?

You can go with `string=re.compile()` but this would be only second best solution.

Better one would be to adjust your `css selector` to get all the itemprop attributes:

```
soup.select('#js-search-product-items [itemprop="itemListElement"]')
```

#### Example

```
...
data_insight = []

for n in range(1):
    pages_url = f"https://www.insight.com/en_US/search.html?qtype=all&q=tp-link&qsrc=k&pq=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A100%2C%22currentPage%22%3A{n+1}%2C%22shownFlag%22%3Afalse%2C%22priceRangeLower%22%3Anull%2C%22priceRangeUpper%22%3Anull%2C%22cmtStandards%22%3Atrue%2C%22categoryId%22%3Anull%2C%22setType%22%3Anull%2C%22setId%22%3Anull%2C%22shared%22%3Anull%2C%22groupId%22%3Anull%2C%22cmtCustomerNumber%22%3Anull%2C%22groupName%22%3Anull%2C%22fromLicense%22%3Atrue%2C%22licenseContractIds%22%3Anull%2C%22assortmentIds%22%3Anull%2C%22controller%22%3Anull%2C%22fromcs%22%3Afalse%2C%22searchTerms%22%3A%7B%22TP-LINK%2520TECHNOLOGY%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22field%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22A-HYBRIS-ManufacturerId~0007045098%22%7D%7D%2C%22sortBy%22%3A%22BestMatch%22%7D"
    driver.get(pages_url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="prod-section-container"]')))
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = Soup(html)
    soup

    for item in soup.select('#js-search-product-items [itemprop="itemListElement"]'):

        data_insight.append({
            'title' : item.find(attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text,
            'sku' : item.find(attrs={'itemprop':'sku'}).text,
            'link' : item.find(attrs={'itemprop':'url'}).text,
            'price' : item.find("span", class_="c-currency__value").text,
            'stock' : item.find("p", class_="prod-stock").get_text(strip=True).split(' ')[0]
        })

df_insight = pd.DataFrame(data_insight)
df_insight.drop_duplicates()
df_insight
```

#### Output

| title | sku | link | price | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TP-Link TL-WR902AC - wireless router - 802.11a/b/g/n/ac - desktop | TL-WR902AC | https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/TL-WR902AC/TP-LINK%20TECHNOLOGY/TL-WR902AC/TPLink-TLWR902AC--wireless-router--80211abgnac--desktop/ | $37.99 | 751 |
| TP-Link Omada ER605 V1 - router - desktop | ER605 | https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/ER605/TP-LINK%20TECHNOLOGY/ER605/TPLink-Omada-ER605-V1--router--desktop/ | $59.99 | 839 |
| TP-Link TL-PA4010 KIT - powerline adapter kit - wall-pluggable | TL-PA4010KIT | https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/TL-PA4010KIT/TP-LINK%20TECHNOLOGY/TL-PA4010KIT/TPLink-TLPA4010-KIT--powerline-adapter-kit--wallpluggable/ | $46.99 | 442 |
| TP-Link Powerline AV2000 - Starter Kit - powerline adapter kit - wall-pluggable | TL-PA9020PKIT1 | https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/TL-PA9020PKIT1/TP-LINK%20TECHNOLOGY/TL-PA9020P%20KIT/TPLink-Powerline-AV2000--Starter-Kit--powerline-adapter-kit--wallpluggable/ | $101.99 | 403 |
| TP-Link TL-WR802N - wireless router - 802.11b/g/n - desktop | TL-WR802N | https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/TL-WR802N/TP-LINK%20TECHNOLOGY/TL-WR802N/TPLink-TLWR802N--wireless-router--80211bgn--desktop/ | $29.99 | 710 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get result below :

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x00786903+2517251]
 Ordinal0 [0x0071F8E1+2095329]
 Ordinal0 [0x00622848+1058888]

Comment: Is this the whole message? Maybe a NoSuchElementException was raised while locating the element `[class="prod-section-container"]`  website loads very slow so it can possibly be that it wont find the element -  Could you **copy code from answer and run again**? It is the same strategy - If exception raises aigain - please post full error.